# null value in entry:blameLogFolder=null. In android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open android studio it give a error while building gradle. I restarted my pc but nothing does. And I also tried to generate apk but same error.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. *What went wrong: null value
>   in entry:blameLogFolder=null *Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get
>   the stack trace. Run with --info or -- debug option to get more log
>   output

Here in brief what exactly happened. I was installing Kotlin plugin. Then accidentally my pc turned off.. then I when I click on android studio to open it gives a lot of error then it closes itself... I tried again..then it started but above error occurred

Comment: can you show the error log?

Comment: @JayPatel  yeah  wait uploading

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*What went wrong:
null value in entry:blameLogFolder=null

*Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- debug option to get more log output

Comment: @JayPatel Here in brief what exactly happened.
I was installing Kotlin plugin. Then accidentally my pc turned off.. then I when I click on android studio to open it gives a lot of error then it closes itself... I tried again..then it started but above error occurred

Comment: @JayPatel Now i started a new project and everything is perfectly then I again opened that project and error still exist...

Comment: @JayPatel Solved it!!

Answer (score 3):

I solved it. I deleted two folders inside my *project/.gradle/3.3*. There were 2 folder named *Tasks Artifacts* and *Tasks*. I deleted both, rebuilt the project and it worked.